# UNION ALL and items selected from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I used UNION ALL to select items for 2 tables, it seems selecting first table items ONLY:

```
SELECT id_shk,
       shk_fname,
       shk_lname,
       shk_tran,
       country_code,
       nationality,
       shk_info,
       shk_title
FROM   sheikh_tbl
WHERE  ( quoran = "1"
          OR baramijaudio = "1"
          OR anachid = "1"
          OR douaedikr = "1"
          OR dorousse = "1" )
       AND ( shk_fname LIKE "%oyoun%"
              OR shk_mname LIKE "%oyoun%"
              OR shk_lname LIKE "%oyoun%" )
UNION ALL
SELECT wtitle,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM   wall
WHERE  wtitle LIKE "%oyoun%"
LIMIT
0, 5
```

Any suggestion about this??

---

I create a test tables, this is result as I said, the field of the second table is not displayed:

[image: enter link description here]

So if I do echo $name, it will not show anything

This is a test in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a161/1/0

Comment: `LIMIT 0, 5` is applied after performing the `UNION`. If the first table returns more than 5 rows, that's all that will show.

Comment: the result is 3 rows, but displaying only one, and I noticed something, once testing on phpmyadmin, the fields name show there are only for first table, and second table are not there, I think that's why if I am printing echo to show them, they do not exists

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle instead of posting an image that we can't tweak?

Comment: I tried, but it failed: Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.:

Comment: Yeah, sqlfiddle seems to be broken tonight, I've been getting that error.

Comment: well, this is a link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a161/1/0

Comment: @Fred, the column name mentioned in the first union would be used for both the union outputs, in your case shk_fname is used, so you need to check for $shk_fname  or change the query and give alias name in the first union. `SELECT name FROM wall_test 
UNION ALL 
SELECT shk_fname as name FROM sheikh_tbl_test`

Comment: @Fred Where do you expect it to put the name from the second table? There's only one column heading. It always uses the column name from the first subquery in the union.

Comment: thanks guys I got it, thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a union, you'll get the row data from all the subqueries. But a column can only have one column name, so the name for the columns in the union are taken from the first subquery.

If you want to make it clearer, you could give an alias that shows that it could be either column.

```
select id_shk AS id_shk_or_wtitle,
       shk_fname,
       shk_lname,
       shk_tran,
       country_code,
       nationality,
       shk_info,
       shk_title
FROM   sheikh_tbl
UNION
SELECT wtitle,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM   wall
```

Answer (score 0):

With union the column names from the first select are used for the the other select(s) as well.
If you need to know from with table rows come from add a pseodo column to each select:

```
SELECT
     'table1' tablename,
     fieldx
FROM
     table1

UNION ALL

SELECT
     'table2',
     fieldy
FROM
     table2
```

Comment: I'm confused with table1 and tablename, I did not understand what you mean

Comment: It's a column alias for the `UNION`.

Comment: so in my case, just to clarify, which one is table1 and which one is tablename